# UITextField not becoming first responder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a `UITextfiled` added via `xib`, added on view number 5 after login.

When I logged in first time and go to view number 5 via navigation,
and click on the `UITextField` to provide inputs, I am not able to do so.
The `textField` is not receiving any event nor the keyboard is getting up.
I tried `[textfield becomeFirstResponder];` in `viewWillAppear:`, still it didn't show keyboard.

But when I close the app and launch again, then its working fine.

Only when I logged in first time my UITextField is not responding.

What may be the problem.

Same scenario is working on lower version of iOS (I tried on iOS 8.3)

Is it the OS compatibility...?
Or
Am I making something wrong...?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: havent u set IBOutLet or u havent set delegate??

Comment: r u doing this on simulator or on device ? @stallone

Comment: @TejaNandamuri :- I am checking on device. not on simulator.

Comment: @vaibby :- I set both IBOutlet and Delegates as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,
disconnect IBOutlet and reconnect it then [textfield becomeFirstResponder] in viewdidAppear: and use this [self.view endEdit:NO];

Comment: what are you doing on view number 4? check his disAppear